# How to find the derivative of stationary point of a function with respect to a parameter

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis

Suppose $f(x;a)$ is a convex function where $a$ is a parameter, and $x^*(a)$ is the minimizer of $f(x;a)$. Is there any formula to determine $\frac{dx^*(a)}{da}$ without finding $x^*(a)$ directly?

Comment: Try implicit differentiation (with respect to $a$) on the formula $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x^*(a),a) = 0$.

Comment: Could you give an example how to do it?

Comment: If $g(x(a),a)=0$ for all $a$, then $0 = \frac{d}{da} g(x(a),a)$ for all $a$ too. Expand this using the chain rule, and apply the result to $g=\partial f/\partial x$.